# Can I make sure that no exception happens on overflow integer miltiplication?

Tags: c++, linux, arithmetic-expressions, integer-arithmetic, overflowexception

I am writing a code that do some arithmetic on long values and it should NOT generate an overflow exception.

The code needs to be compiled both on windows (visual studio ) and Linux (ARM Linux).

Is there any pragma or compile time directive that I can use to tell the compile that it should not generate an overflow exception for that specific code.

The main point here is:

1- It works both on windows and Linux

2- Irrespective of the general configuration of project, this section should not generate an overflow exception. (so setting a parameter in project is not a good solution).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are no exceptions (in the meaning of C++ exception) when an overflow occurs.

Comment: In practice, integer multiplication won't generate an exception. C/C++ require that *unsigned* integer multiplication not overflow, if you want a guarantee.

Comment: @BrettHale Thanks. What about signed integer? Does it generate overflow?

Comment: It's technically undefined behaviour. Which means a correct C/C++ program should *not* result in a signed overflow. Which in turn means you should avoid such an operation, or use unsigned arithmetic. That said, 'undefined behaviour' may include 'do nothing' - x86[-64] for example.

Comment: @BrettHale 'undefined behavior' my include 'give wrong results' as well; in fact, if the results don't fit in the target type, it's practically impossible for a compiler to do anything else (except raise an exception or a signal of some sort, but such implementations are rare).

Comment: @JamesKanze - I think that's implicit in my comment. And most architectures will set an overflow flag that can be queried - but will not raise an exception.

Comment: @BrettHale The overflow flag cannot be queried in C++.

Comment: @JamesKanze - I said the 'architecture'. You are being deliberately obtuse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any implementation which will generate an
overflow exception for expressions with integral type.  But the
question is: what do you want it to do.  All of the Windows and
Linux compilers I know will simply silently give the wrong
results, and I can't think of a situation where this would be
preferable to *any* alternative.

The normal way of handling this sort of problem is by using
pre-condition checks, before starting the calculations.  You
know the calculations which are going to be done, so you can
determine the range of values which can safely be handled
without overflow, and you verify the input is in that range
before starting.

Comment: What I want is to the overflow data is lost. So for example if I have byte x=128,  byte y=129, then byte c=x+y, C should be 1 and there should be no exception.

Comment: That's the rule for unsigned arithmetic.  But why?  Why shoud  `c` be `1`?